# Caps Lock is mapped to Shift

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Sometime today, something occurred with my machine where the caps lock key is now mapped to Shift.  It's annoying as I need to use Caps Lock for, among other things, a spreadsheet that I'm working on (not to mention CRUISE CONTROL, etc).

The only remotely plausible cause for this is the following registry entry, located at the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
```

The key is as follows:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,2a,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

I don't have anything like AutoHotKey or such installed, and I didn't get a new keyboard, or change my keymapping.  I lock my PC while it's unattended, and I run the domain here, so it's not someone else messing with my stuff.

Comment: Does it persist over a reboot?

Comment: Is it definitely caps lock, or just the first key press after pressing shift results in a capital letter?

Comment: It persists after a reboot.  And Marko, when I say caps lock is mapped to the shift key, it shows up as the left shift key on On Screen Keyboard, and pressing Caps Lock 5 times will make the Sticky Keys dialog come up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my XP there is no "Scancode Map", just deleting that value should reset keyboard layout to default.

Some people here at my office prefer to swap r-ctrl with caps lock. Got the following .reg scripts to change this:

caps-ctrl-swap.reg:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,3a,00,1d,00,00,00,00,00
```

Is for swaping

caps-as-ctrl.reg:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

Is for mapping capslock to ctrl only

(reboot might be needed after changing those, but unsure)

Comment: I deleted that registry entry, and it's still happening.

Comment: Did you reboot after? If so, is the registry value still gone?

Comment: What do you know, it works.