# Caps lock key behavior on PS/2 keyboard is reversed

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, capslock, ps2

I'm on a Windows 7 desktop with an external ps2 keyboard and its Caps lock key is behaving in opposite manner, like when I turn on the caps lock and the caps lock key light is lit its typing in small alphabets and vice-versa. It works fine for a while after rebooting the system however it re-appears again so I'm trying to resolve the cause.

I've gone through several forums and here are the several things I've tried :

1. Press both shift keys down.
2. Press tab and check if some shift key is down.
3. Check for sticky keys.

I've also read that it could be some program modifying the way caps lock works but that's not the case either because I've checked the task manager and there is no such strange process running which could do so.

I've tried using On screen keyboard and its showed that the caps lock key is pressed whereas on my physical keyboard it wasn't and vice-versa. What could be the possible cause ? Thanks for any suggestions or help in advance.

Comment: Related [question](https://superuser.com/questions/684510/win7-after-prolonged-usage-weird-keyboard-things-happening-caps-lock-stuck?rq=1), but nothing worked among given answers.

Comment: thanks, i had the same issue but pressing both shift keys fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark from [this forum post](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-650212-help-my-caps-lock-working-in-reverse), which is the only one I found that didn't suggest a stuck shift key (as your on screen keyboard displays caps lock on):

> Try this trick. Go into Microsoft Word and type "tHANKS" and it will autocorrect it back to "Thanks" and your keyboard should be in sync with your monitor. I've noticed that my screen says the caps lock is off but my keyboard says it is on and after I try this trick it works again.

It sounds weird but it's got 38 upvotes and a whole lot of "thanks"; I do not know what the root cause is.

Comment: Thanks Jason, for now its working properly so whenever I face the issue again, will try it out and keep you posted.

Answer (score 7):

Hold down CAPS LOCK+CTRL+SHIFT

Comment: how come this only has two upvotes?!